# locking on correlation id in aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

Looking at the code for AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler it seems like a lock is obtained based on correlation id by the aggregator to enforce processing the message group belonging to the same correlation id by a single thread. This makes sense and in fact i wanted to make sure that once messages are released from an aggregator as long as they are being worked on by any downstream component within the same thread as they were released in, the aggregator shouldnt release any more messages belonging to same correlation id (if they come in).

So e.g. If I send message "A" with correlation id as "1" and immediately send message "B" belonging to same correlation id and let aggregator release both. Now If I have some time consuming components after the aggregator I want to not release "B" until the thread processing "A" is all done. Keeping in mind that A and B are being processed by different threads. At the same time if I send "C" with correlation id as "2" I do want this to be released while "A" is being processed.

So this is desired behavior and surprisingly this is exactly how it seems to work. So the aggregator is handling the locking logic as intended. I just want to understand how thats happening does that means that the aggregator places the lock before releasing a message group and then releases the lock until after all components downstream have been processed basically the postSend have been called on them. Looking at the code for class mentioned above it seems to release the lock after releasing the message but thats not what I see when running my example. Instead the lock is held until all downstream components after the aggregator have completed. I am hoping for some clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to simplify it a bit the logic looks like:

```
lock.lockInterruptibly();
try {
   completeGroup(message, correlationKey, messageGroup);
}
finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

And I think should agree with me that `unlock()` will be done only after `completeGroup()` will finish its work. The last one may do any hard and long work and the `lock` will be holded all that time.

So, if your downstream flow (the subsriber for aggregator's `output-channel`) is single-threaded (all endpoint are tied with `DirectChannel`), the `lock` won't be unlocked until all those endpoint will finish their work. `MessageHandler`s subscribe to channels and send message to channels. Everything is done within the same Call Stack.

Comment: yup thats what i thought too just needed a confirmation.

Comment: Sorry, not sure in your question. It is `lock`, so everything within it is in the exclusive mode and all other threads just wait for the lock.